# Perl hash of array - numerical sort of alphanumeric keys

Tags: arrays, perl, sorting, hash, alphanumeric

I understand that the default sort in Perl is an ASCII sort, not numerical. But how can I numerically sort strings that have numbers?

For example, I have a hash of arrays, like so:

```
myhash{ANN20021015_0101_XML_71.9} = ("anta", "hunna", "huma");
myhash{ANN20021115_0049_XML_14.1} = ("lqd", "qAl", "arrajul");
myhash{ANN20021115_0049_XML_14.2} = ("anna", "alwalada");
```

I just need the keys to be sorted...but the sorting is numerical within strings. I can't do a string sort, because I end up with "10" following "1", but I can't do a numerical sort either!

Comment: Probably useful: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html

Answer (score 6):

First of all your code isn't valid Perl and may not do what you think it does. Always

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
```

at the head of your program to resolve any simple mistakes. The code should look like

```
  $myhash{'ANN20021015_0101_XML_71.9'} = ["anta", "hunna", "huma"];
  $myhash{'ANN20021115_0049_XML_14.1'} = ["lqd", "qAl", "arrajul"];
  $myhash{'ANN20021115_0049_XML_14.2'} = ["anna", "alwalada"];
```

To sort on something other than the entire value, you can transform `$a` and `$b` within the sort block, and sort the result numerically `<=>` instead of stringwise `<=>`. This code does what you need

```
  my @sorted = sort {
    my ($aa) = $a =~ /.*_(.+)/;
    my ($bb) = $b =~ /.*_(.+)/;
    $aa <=> $bb;
  } keys %myhash;
```

But if you have a large amount of data it may be profitable to use the [*Schwartzian Transform*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) which will avoid extracting the numeric part of your strings every time they are compared

```
  my @sorted = map  { $_->[0] }
               sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
               map  { /.*_(.+)/ and [$_, $1] }
               keys %myhash;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a custom sort: cut your strings into parts you **know** are literals/numbers and compare those as needed.

From your example it looks like you want `literal`.`digits`, but you can change the regular expression so that it fits you.

```
my $cut = qr/(.*?\.)(\d+)(.*)/;
sort { 
    my @a = $a =~ $cut; my @b = $b =~ $cut; 
    $a[0] cmp $b[0] || $a[1] <=> $b[1] || $a[2] cmp $b[2] 
} keys %myhash;
```

See also [Borodin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092486/perl-hash-of-array-numerical-sort-of-alphanumeric-keys/8092929#8092929).